# How is the FPA (flight-path-angle) computed?

Tags: flight-controls, non-precision-approach

How is FPA computed by the Auto-pilot to follow the  desired FPA? One part is clearly VS, is the other part IAS or Ground speed? Where does Ground speed come from?

Answer (score 2):

The flight path is a path defined with respect to the **ground**. Therefore, the flight path angle must be computed with the **ground speed**:

[image: Flight Path Angle]

The flight path angle $\alpha$ is calculated by the on-board computers with:

$$ \alpha = \text{arctan} \left( \frac{V/S}{\text{GS}} \right) $$

The source of the ground speed would in general be aircraft dependent, but for an airliner this would come from the [Air Data Inertial Reference System (ADIRS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_data_inertial_reference_unit). See also [How is the actual ground speed of an airliner measured?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/how-is-the-actual-ground-speed-of-an-airliner-measured)

Some non-precision approach charts will also have a table with required vertical speeds for various *ground speeds* to maintain the target flight path angle. This is particularly helpful if your aircraft **cannot fly a given** FPA itself. This is an example from Amsterdam Schiphol (EHAM) VOR Approach for runway 09:

[image: Ground Speed]

If you e.g. fly with a ground speed of 150kt on this approach, you would just dial in 800ft/min and you would get the desired 3° FPA.